# react native navigation3 I want to hide one label of bottom tab navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

[image]

I want to hide the label which is highlighted in yellow in the picture.

How to do that?

My code:

```
const MainBottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack : {
    screen : HomeStack,
    navigationOptions : {
      showlabel:false,
      drawerLabel:NullComponent
    }
  } ,
  SettingsStack,
  },{
  tabBarPosition:"bottom",
  navigationOptions:{

  },
  tabBarOptions:{

activeTintColor: "green",
inactiveTintColor: "#00ccff",
style:{
  backgroundColor: "white"
},
indicatorStyle:{
  height: 0
},
showIcon:'true'


},
 swipeEnabled:true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use custom TabIcon

```
 navigationOptions :({ navigation }) {
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {

    const { routeName } = navigation.state;
    let iconName;
    if (routeName === 'Home') iconName = 'home';
    else if (routeName === 'Notifications') iconName = 'notifications';
    else if (routeName === 'Readout') iconName = 'readout';
    else if (routeName === 'Inbox') iconName = 'messages';
    else if (routeName === 'Profile') iconName = 'profile';
 //Tabicon is just custom Icon display widget . handle All tabicon in TabIcon by iconname 
     return <TabIcons iconName={iconName} tintColor={tintColor} />;

 }
}
```

Comment: can u explain more?? I really need that

Comment: check my working application for custom icons in tab navigator[check my application navigator](https://github.com/AurangzaibRamzan/Anime-jisho/blob/master/src/containers/app/MainTabNavigator.js  )